# Ruby change the order of hash keys

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I have a hash and I would like the change the key order from.

```
{"result"=>{"data"=>[{"Quantity"=>13, "Rate"=>17.1},
                    {"Quantity"=>29,"Rate"=>3.2}, 
                    {"Quantity"=>7, "Rate"=>3.4}]}}
```

To:

```
{"result"=>{"data"=>[{"Rate"=>17.1, "Quantity"=>13}, 
                    {"Rate"=>3.2, "Quantity"=>29}, 
                    {"Rate"=>3.4, "Quantity"=>7}]}}
```

that can be accessed by `hash["result"]["data"]`. I tried;

```
hash["result"]["data"][0].each_value{|v| v.replace({"Rate" => v.delete("Rate")}.merge(v))}
```

But it gives error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `delete' for
>    17.1:Float):

Comment: Why do you want to change the order of the keys? Why do you care? What do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
hash["result"]["data"].each{|v| v.replace({"Rate" => v.delete("Rate")}.merge(v))}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think their is no need to do this much of operations. I suppose `data` contains your whole hash then just one map and reverse of hash will resolve your problem.

```
data['result']['data'] = data['result']['data'].map{|v|  Hash[v.to_a.reverse]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Four more ways...

Reverse the order of those hash items:

```
hash['result']['data'].map! { |h| h.to_a.reverse.to_h }
```

Move "Quantity" to the end:

```
hash['result']['data'].each { |h| h["Quantity"] = h.delete("Quantity") }
```

Move the first item to the end:

```
hash['result']['data'].map! { |h| h.merge([h.shift].to_h) }
```

Force a certain given order:

```
keys = ["Rate", "Quantity"]
hash['result']['data'].map! { |h| keys.zip(h.values_at(*keys)).to_h }
```

Comment: Hey @Stefan Pochmann! I'm using **force a certain given order**. It maps integer values correctly but converting strings into nil. Can you help me how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```rb
hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
hash.slice!(:b, :a)
puts hash # { :b => 2, :a => 1 }
```